# Can I drop a foreign key without using constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
ALTER TABLE table1  
ADD FOREIGN KEY attrib1 REFERENCES table2(attrib2)
GO
```

It works - but how can I drop it?

If I try

```
DROP FOREIGN KEY (attrib1) REFERENCES table2(attrib2)
```

it says

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.

Comment: alter table table1 drop constraint attrib1

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server you need to drop foreign key constraint by using below query:

Query :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_Name] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name]
```

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SpeakerDetail] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_SpeakerId_UserID]
```

Comment: What constraint will I drop if I didnt put constraint to the foreign key?


    `ALTER TABLE table1  
    ADD FOREIGN KEY attrib1 REFERENCES table2(attrib2)
    GO`                                                     
^This is the syntax I put and it works without constraint.

Comment: No need to be confused, as the Foreign key was created with a Constraint name  .
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FOREIGN KEY attrib1 REFERENCES table2(attrib2)  in this foreign key name is the constraint that you need to drop.

Comment: Another option you can use is Open database, right click on the table , then click on Keys ,you can easily drop FOREIGN KEY by this.